# NSUserDefaults are not being written to disk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I set some values to NSUserDefaults and if I retrieve them without exiting the app, everything works fine.
When I restart the app, the changes disappear in 95% of the time. In 5% of the time everything is being saved ok.

I'm facing this problem for the first time. In my other apps I don't usually save NSString in NSUserDefaults. May the fact of saving NSString cause problems?

Here's my code:

```
    -(void) mayShowFeedbackMessage
    {
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormatter setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
     [dateFormatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

     if ([ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"ratingsMessage_shown_on_date"])
     {
          NSString *lastRatingDateString = [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                           objectForKey: @"ratingsMessage_shown_on_date"];
          NSDate *lastRatingDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: lastRatingDateString];

          DebugLog(@"lastRatingDateString: %@", lastRatingDateString);
          DebugLog(@"time since last message: %.0f", [ [NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: lastRatingDate]);

          if ( [ [NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: lastRatingDate] >= 120.0f )
          {
              [self showFeedbackMessage];

              NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
              [dateFormatter setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
              [dateFormatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

              NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date] ];
             [dateFormatter release];

             [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: dateString
                                                        forKey: @"ratingsMessage_shown_on_date" ];

             lastRatingDateString = [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                     objectForKey: @"ratingsMessage_shown_on_date"];
             DebugLog(@"new date: %@", lastRatingDateString);

         }
     }
     else
     {  
         NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [dateFormatter setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
         [dateFormatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

         NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date] ];
         [dateFormatter release];

         [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: dateString
                                                        forKey: @"ratingsMessage_shown_on_date" ];

         NSString *lastRatingDateString = [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                                objectForKey: @"ratingsMessage_shown_on_date"];
         DebugLog(@"new date: %@", lastRatingDateString);

     }

         [dateFormatter release];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding the following code after doing the necessary changes solved the issue:

```
[ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary as of 10.8 and later: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.html “[Synchronization] is now automatic in virtually all cases. The only remaining reason to call it is if you need a separate process to be able to…access the values you just set; for example if you set a preference, then…another process…reads the same preference. Most regular app…s will never need to do this, and app…s that do are encouraged to use an inter-process communication API (for example XPC)…rather than using the preferences system for IPC.”

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth you can look at your defaults with the Property Editor to see if it's being written correctly:

```
open ~/Library/Preferences/org.your.app.plist
```

or just dump them:

```
defaults read org.your.app
```

Answer (score 1):

NSuserDefualts was not saving my values on game crash.
by using,
 `[ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`
the vales are getting saved.